# How to change function status to invalid?

Tags: oracle, alter, stored-functions

I have a function that using a lot of objects.

I want to make that function status invalid with no touching the function code and with no touching the objects (for some tests).

Is there a way to make function invalid with a command?

something like:

```
alter function .. invalid;
```

I'm using Oracle 11g.

Comment: Huh. You opted out two (simple) ways to do that. I don't know the third one.

Comment: I need to simulate a case that the function become invalid because of one of the tables inside is drop and recreate (in another function). but in production environment I don't want to recreate the table.

Comment: Create a table or sequence.
Add the use of this table or sequence to the function.
Modify the table or delete the sequence and you will get a change in the state of your function.

Comment: Marking a function as "invalid" is something that oracle does for you automatically. It merely indicates that a recompilation might be required. Barring an obscure oracle bug you can't simulate this without changing either the function definition or an object it is dependent on.

Answer (score 0):

You may easily invalidate a function by `REVOKE`ing  some privilege.

Example - the function has granted select on a table `HR.JOBS`

```
create function job_cnt return number as
 v_cnt NUMBER;
begin
 select count(*) into v_cnt from hr.jobs;
 return (v_cnt);
end;
/
```

and is `VALID`

```
select OBJECT_NAME, STATUS from user_objects where object_name = 'JOB_CNT';

OBJECT_NAME  STATUS 
------------ -------
JOB_CNT      VALID
```

By `REVOKE`ing the privilege it's immediately invalidated.

```
revoke select on hr.jobs from your_user;

select OBJECT_NAME, STATUS from user_objects where object_name = 'JOB_CNT';

OBJECT_NAME  STATUS 
------------ -------
JOB_CNT      INVALID
```

Note, that this works only with access to object from other owners, which required explicit `GRANTS` for the access.